# MS Access 2007 syntax: From Join Join Join Where

Tags: sql, join, ms-access-2007, where-clause

I'm working in Access 2007, and I'm a lot more comfortable with SQL than with Access. After reading several threads on this site related to joins in MS Access, I think I"m doing this correctly, but I am being told I have a syntax error on my where clause. Here is the new, improved? version:

```
FROM (( Patron P
    INNER JOIN Patron_Address PA1 ON
    (PA1.patron_id = P.patron_id)
     LEFT JOIN Patron_Address PA2 ON
      (PA2.patron_id = P.patron_id)     
     LEFT JOIN Patron_Address PA3 ONL
      (PA3.patron_id = P.patron_id) 
  where PA1.address_type = '1'AND
        PA2.address_type = '2' AND
         PA3.address_type = '3';
```

Let me explain my goal. 
patron tuples have 1-3 patron_address tuples.
These address rows have three types:

1. permanent
2. temporary
3. email

Also,

- A patron must have a patron_address row for address_type 1
- A patron may have a patron_address row for address_type 2
- A patron may have a patron_address row for address_type 3

I need to get the address information for all the address rows for every patron_id. The data from each address row needs to go into columns in a lare query result set that I then need to turn into a tab-delimited file to send to a vendor.

This is why I am doing a join and this is why I need to use criteria.
Logically, the result of each join should have its own where clause, but that's apparently not allowed. So I have one where clause that lists three conditions.  The problem there is that only one of the three conditions applies to each join.

So what do I need to do conceptually and syntactically to get the result I want? Thanks for help with this monster the last few days. I'm getting close, I think. Then again, I may have simply moved my error.

Comment: I've made the SQL render a little better, but it could perhaps still do with the indents being tidied up. Using the preview facilities and making sure your question looks nice probably helps to get answers.

Comment: *I'm a lot more comfortable with SQL than with Access*...interesting remark given Access runs SQL, the special-purpose declarative programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the below query:-

```
 FROM Patron P 
 INNER JOIN Patron_Address PA1 ON PA1.patron_id = P.patron_id)
 LEFT JOIN Patron_Address PA2 ON PA2.patron_id = P.patron_id
LEFT JOIN Patron_Address PA3 ON PA3.patron_id = P.patron_id
where PA1.address_type = '1'
AND PA2.address_type = '2' 
AND PA3.address_type = '3';
```

Technically, I have removed all the brackets and the letter "L" on the last "ON". You typed "ONL" instead of "ON"

Comment: In formatting the block for code, I didn't know where the L in LEFT had gone. Your version of the from clause produced a "Syntax error in From". I added a ( before the first table, and now it is giving me an error on the next JOIN:FROM (Patron P 
 INNER JOIN Patron_Address PA1 ON PA1.patron_id = P.patron_id)
 LEFT JOIN Patron_Address PA2 ON PA2.patron_id = P.patron_id
LEFT JOIN Patron_Address PA3 ON PA3.patron_id = P.patron_id
where PA1.address_type = '1'
AND PA2.address_type = '2' AND PA3.address_type = '3';

Comment: I added parens for the second join as well and for the moment I am not getting a complaint from Access about the joins anymore. Now it is complaining about the very first column,  "select PATRON.TITLE, " in that it is asking me to input a TITLE.  It should select not ask for input.  So I don't know what I have done wrong now. The full query is too long to put into a comment, so I am not sure how to show it.

Comment: Here is my FROM clause that is not presently getting an error:FROM ((Patron P 
 INNER JOIN Patron_Address PA1 ON PA1.patron_id = P.patron_id)
 LEFT JOIN Patron_Address PA2 ON PA2.patron_id = P.patron_id)
LEFT JOIN Patron_Address PA3 ON PA3.patron_id = P.patron_id

Comment: Is the FROM clause making Access think there should be only one row, period?  If I try to run the query, it asks for the value of the parameter PATRON.TITLE: select PATRON.TITLE,
PATRON.FIRST_NAME, 
PATRON.MIDDLE_NAME, 
PATRON.LAST_NAME,
' ',
' ',
' ',
' ',
'5692',
PATRON.BARCODE,
' ',

Comment: I have worked on this more. I found that MS Access 2007 could not handle a subquery as a field.  Bummer.  So I had to make my from clause more compliacated. Now it works but only returns about 20 rows instead of thousands: SELECT  P.patron_id, PB.patron_barcode, PA1.city

FROM (((PATRON P INNER JOIN PATRON_BARCODE PB ON P.PATRON_ID = PB.PATRON_ID)
                               INNER JOIN PATRON_ADDRESS PA1 ON PB.PATRON_ID = PA1.PATRON_ID)
LEFT JOIN Patron_Address PA2 ON PA2.patron_id 

= P.patron_id)
LEFT JOIN Patron_Address PA3 ON PA3.patron_id 

= P.patron_id  where same as before.